# Need to pull sql statement ordered by a column based on its value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a list of all words in my dictionary ordered by the amount of "yes" votes it received.

Here is an example of the tables dictionary and vote:

Table dictionary:

```
dictionary_id     dictionary_word
1                 Dog
2                 Cat
3                 Pig
```

Table vote:

```
vote_id       dictionary_id     vote_path
1             3                 yes
2             3                 yes
3             1                 yes
4             2                 no
5             1                 no
6             1                 no
```

Here is the sql statement I've started making, the problem is I need to order it by the COUNT of votes that are yes, not just the number of votes tied to one dictionary_id

```
SELECT * 
FROM dictionary 
LEFT JOIN vote ON dictionary.dictionary_id = vote.dicionary_id 
GROUP BY dictionary.dictionary_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(vote_id) DESC
```

Comment: move the count from the order clause to the select clause

Comment: @Leo - how would that help?

Answer (score 1):

try using a conditional order like this.

**NOTE:** (with one exception) `LEFT JOIN x WHERE x` is the same as `INNER JOIN x WHERE x` .. in this case you only need a JOIN

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM dictionary d
JOIN vote v ON d.dictionary_id = v.dictionary_id 
GROUP BY d.dictionary_id 
ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN v.vote_path = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5075f9/2)

**OUTPUT:**

```
+--------------+---------------+-------+----------+-----------------+
|DICTIONARY_ID |DICTIONARY_WORD|VOTE_ID|VOTE_PATH | NUMBER_OF_YESSES|
+--------------+---------------+-------+----------+-----------------+
|    3         |    Pig        |    1  |    yes   |         2       |
|    1         |    Dog        |    3  |    yes   |         1       |
|    2         |    Cat        |    4  |    no    |         0       |
+--------------+---------------+-------+----------+-----------------+
```

if you want you can just do the SUM(CASE....) only once in the select and reference it in the ORDER BY for even faster speeds like so

```
SELECT 
    *,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.vote_path = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as number_of_yesses 
FROM dictionary d
JOIN vote v ON d.dictionary_id = v.dictionary_id 
GROUP BY d.dictionary_id 
ORDER BY number_of_yesses DESC
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5075f9/5)

Comment: not quite John, i think OP want the yes votes in order of number of yeses also.

Comment: @Randy this will order by the number of yesses

Comment: yes it works too :) but you do it without calling the sum(cas.... int the select statement

Comment: @Youness I just added the sum(case... ) in the select so the OP has the number of yes votes as well... its interchangable

Answer (score 1):

**untested**

```
SELECT * 
FROM dictionary d
LEFT JOIN vote v ON d.dictionary_id = v.dictionary_id 
GROUP BY d.dictionary_id 
ORDER BY (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM vote AS vo1
  WHERE vo1.dictionary_id=d.dictionary_id AND vo1.vote_path="yes"
) DESC
```

Comment: This works :) but its not necessary to do another query.. see my answer :)

Comment: +1 for an untested version that works and is still minimal :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  *
  , (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM vote
    WHERE dictionary.dictionary_id = vote.dicionary_id
      AND vote_path = 'yes'
  ) AS yes_cnt
FROM dictionary 
ORDER BY yes_cnt DESC
```

Comment: this is a correlated subquery.. you should specify the negative effects of using one when proposing it as an answer. this could potentially be very slow if hes working with big tables... every time one row is selected ALL rows are selected to compare to that one row.

Comment: You could actually move the whole subquery to the order by part and don't put it in SELECT at all, if the count() is needed for sorting only.

Comment: it doesn't need another query.. look at my answer

Comment: But a Join won't be faster, would it?

Comment: yes a join would be. because a join you do the select once and then compare the rows row by row... a correlated subquery does a select of all rows in the table for every row in the table.. if that makes sense :)

Comment: again just check the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have this

```
create table dic (id int, name varchar(255));
create table votes (vid int, id int, vote int);
insert into dic values (1,'dog');
insert into dic values (2,'cat');
insert into dic values (3,'mouse');
insert into votes values (1,1,1);
insert into votes values (2,1,1);
insert into votes values (3,1,0);
insert into votes values (4,1,0);
insert into votes values (5,2,1);
insert into votes values (6,2,1);
insert into votes values (7,3,0);
```

then if you do this

```
select d.name, count(v.vid) as c
from dic d, votes v 
where d.id = v.id
and v.vote = 1
group by d.id
order by c
```

you'll have this

```
NAME    C
dog     2
cat     2
```

Comment: this is the old fashoned way to do a join... the JOIN keyword is optimized to run faster than the Cartesian Product of the two tables then filtered by a where

Comment: I am old-fashioned :-)

Comment: :) understandable.. its just a bit slower than the regular join.. pointing it out for other passers by :)

Comment: well if I can find where I read that I'll post the link... but think about it... this is doing the Cartesian Product of the two tables... so it joins them on all matching fields which depending on the table could double even triple (or more) the number of rows/matches... then it goes through and filters out with the where. the JOIN on the other hand has the ON clause that filters row by row satisfying the requirements. so its generally faster :)

Comment: Well after looking around I can't find where I read that... but I also read some stuff that clarified that it didn't have a performance effect, so I'll retract what I said since I cant seem to prove it :)... there were notes about how its better/safer to write with JOIN syntax as it'll provide less user error (user could accidentally not filter correctly, which would be the Cartesian Product)

Comment: i don't think so John... all you need to do is check the explain plan to see that there is no terrible 'join everything' step going on in the 'old fashioned' syntax.